# Check if user is 18 y.o

Tags: input

So I am currently working on a project and trying to check if the user is over 18 and I can't get my logic right. Here are my statements and the error code:

```
if ($dobYear<date("Y")-19) 
if ($dobYear==date("Y")-18 and $dobMon<date("m"))
if ($dobYear==date("Y") and $dobMon==date("m") and $dobDay<=date("d"))

$err['lowAge'] = 'You must be over 18 to register!';
```

$dobMon, $dobDay and $dobYear come from the user input (3 forms).

An article that can help me would be enough, no need of doing everything for me :)

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Whatever solution you find, make sure it works even if someone's birthday is on February the 29th or if today is February the 29th

Comment: I had the format validation complete, but I just cannot figure it out how I can tell PHP to go through the checks the way I want it. I have a bit of experience but this is a real bummer.

Answer (score 1):

I used python for this, but the logic should follow:

```
def set_adult(self):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - self.date_of_birth.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.date_of_birth.month, self.date_of_birth.day))
    self.adult = (age >= 18)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand how your age = works, can you please explain (with the "<" sign)

Comment: Certainly. I'll explain through an example. Consider your birthday is January 1, 1990 (1/1/1990). Assume today is October 31, 2008 (10-31-2008).

today.year = 2008, date_of_birth.year = 1990. Obviously the difference between these is 18, but you're not 18 right? You know that (date_of_birth.month, date_of_birth.day) > (today.month, today.day), so this returns a 1 (true). 18-1=17. Not an adult.